# Can an AJAX form request replace elements of different types?

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm trying to write an AJAX form in Drupal 8. I managed to get a simple example working yesterday, but today, my work fails without error. I was wondering whether anyone here could spot my error.

Here are the relevant excerpts from my OverviewForm:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  ...

  $form['job_id'] = [
    '#weight' => 1,
    '#title' => 'Job',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $formatted_jobs,
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => '::showFiles',
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrappper' => 'jobfiles'
    ]
  ];

  $form['jobfiles'] = [
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#title' => 'Files',
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'span',
    '#value' => 'Please make a selection above',
    '#attributes' => [
      'id' => ['jobfiles']
    ] 
  ];

  return $form;
}

public function showFiles(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $job_id = $form_state->getValue('job_id');
  $elem = [
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#type' => 'item_list',
    '#items' => $this->_files($job_id),
    '#attributes' => [
      'id' => ['jobfiles']
    ]
  ];

  return $elem;
}
```

The list of jobs populates correctly, but when I select one, the initial jobfiles span isn't replaced with anything. I'd expect it to at least disappear when I select a value from the select. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should try using #prefix/#suffix for wrapper instead the element itself. Also IMHO it's not a good idea mess around with the elements you send during build. Take in mind the the build is done every time you render the form, even for AJAX calls. A possible solution could be hide the second element using Form States API and put the *Please make selection* in your prior element.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Code excerpt.
  $form['job_id'] = [
    '#weight' => 1,
    '#title' => t('Job'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#empty_value' => t('Please select a job'),
    '#options' => $formatted_jobs,
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => [get_class($this), 'showFiles'],
      'wrapper' => 'ajax-wrapper',
      'event' => 'change',
    ],
    '#required' => TRUE,
  ];

  // Render a hidden and empty list.
  $form['jobfiles'] = [
    '#weight' => 2,
    '#title' => t('Files'),
    '#type' => 'item_list',
    '#items' => [],
    '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['invisible']
    ]
  ];

  return $form;
}

public function showFiles(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $job_id = $form_state->getValue('job_id');
  $form['jobfiles']['#items'] = $this->_files((int)$job_id);
  // Remove the 'invisible' class.
  $form['jobfiles']['#attributes']['class'] = array_filter($form['jobfiles']['#attributes']['class'], function($v) {
    return $v != 'invisible';
  });
  // You could also return the element instead.
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#ajax-wrapper', [$form['jobfiles']]));

  return $response;
}
```

Hope this may help you.

**Update**:
Replace `$element` with `$form`. Also worth checking the [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/266761/57634) provided by @joshua-moore as it is valid too.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. Unfortunately, all I get is the little spinner and a little Please Wait sign. It disappears after half a second or so, but nothing shows up, even when I hardcode `$this->_files($job_id)`.

Comment: With a little bit of extra googling, I got your answer to work. Thank you! Have my upvote...

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer in the hopes that it saves someone else some googling.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    ...

    $form['job_id'] = [
      '#weight' => 1,
      '#title' => t('Job'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $formatted_jobs,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::showFiles',
        'wrapper' => 'ajax-wrapper'
      ],
      '#required' => TRUE
    ];

    $form['jobfiles'] = [
      '#weight' => 2,
      '#title' => t('Files'),
      '#theme' => 'item_list',
      '#items' => [],
      '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function showFiles(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $job_id = $form_state->getValue('job_id');

    $elem = [
      '#title' => t('Files'),
      '#weight' => 2,
      '#theme' => 'item_list',
      '#items' => $this->_files((int)$job_id)
    ];

    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#ajax-wrapper', $renderer->render($elem)));

    return $response;
  }
```

This works. Thank you, d70rr3s for your answer.

Comment: Hmm the render array wasn't getting rendered? Interesting :o I'll take a closer look but I though both AjaxResponse or the returning value from the AJAX callback can be either a render array or rendered output. Thanks for the upvote, I'll update my answer with your code.

Comment: I think I see why my code was not working and is because in the showFiles method I'm using `$element` instead of `$form` :) any way thanks!